# FLASH_MODE_TORCH not working on Samung Galaxy SIII GT-I9300 Android 4.1.2, SDK 16

Tags: android, android-camera, camera-flash

I don't have the ability to test on the Galaxy SIII so I was hoping somebody faced the same issue. It used to work fine according to the user, but suddenly it stopped working. Reboot, Reinstall, same issue. The LED on the back (Flash) doesn't turn on anymore.

Since I can't see the LOG it's hard to tell why it suddenly stopped working.

It's a Samsung Galaxy SIII (GT-I9300) running on Android 4.1.2 SDK16.

I pass a true to the following method to turn on the flash:

```
public void setTorch(boolean on){
        if (!hasTorch()){return;}
        if (mCamera==null){surfaceCreated(mHolder);return;}
         String _model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
         String _manufaturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
         camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
         List<String> flashModes = camParams.getSupportedFlashModes();

        if (on){

             if((_model.contains("GT-S5830") && _manufaturer.contains("samsung"))){
                  camParams.set("flash-mode", "on");
                  mCamera.setParameters(camParams);                   
             } else {
                    camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
                    camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    mCamera.setParameters(camParams);      
                                 }

        } else {
            camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
                }
    }
```